# Is it possible to use EJB 3.1 in desktop applications?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.1

Is this possible?  Does anyone ever do this?  I feel like I can lay out my application better if I use what I'm used to in web applications.  Would it possible to use this and dependency injection?

If this is not possible or a viable solution can anyone point me to a couple of example projects using JPA and EntityManger to query databases.  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't been using it for long, but I remember that I used a web-service.

Comment: Except for JPA, which will work in Java SE, which parts of the EJB stack do you want to use ? Of course you will need to embed a container for everything else except for JPA.

Comment: Well I like the dependency injection and transaction management that comes with EJB 3.1.  A lot easier for rollbacks, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, it is possible, but the stack is still heavy (both, in terms of resources and, more importantly, maintenance, installation etc.) I wouldn't do it, I would prefer MyBatis. Alternatively, use Hibernate, if you want to stay with JPA-like query language.

There is nothing wrong with using the concept of dependency injection, and Spring is widely used in many desktop apps.

Comment: The JPA part of EJB 3 can be used in any Java environment, and there is no heavy stack associated with it.

Comment: @James: JPA is not a part of EJB 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the JPA part of EJB 3.1 in Java SE or any Java environment.  Most EJB 3 implementations of SessionBeans and such are normally coupled with an application server.

Spring offers dependency injection in any environment and supports JPA.

Comment: Yea I know about the JPA part.  I already have that in my application.  I want transaction management and rollbacks that EJB 3.1 has.  But yea I was messing with spring earlier and it is XML hell and add's like 4000 dependency's just so I can use @Transactional.  I think I'll just stick with the old way.  You would think they would come up with something on Jave SE like they have in Java EE.  Oh well.